# Enterprise application Structure for Asp.Net Core 2 & Angular 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I'm struggling to setup a solution structure for an enterprise application which is based on Asp.net core 2 and angular 6, We have lots of modules which should be placed in different projects while using some shared panels. I Already explored some software development techniques like Microservice, Clean Architecture ... But not sure what to pick.

I would appreciate for some tips or any sample architecture .

regards

Comment: Try to use https://nrwl.io/ for angular

Answer (score 0):

At my current project we use the exact same techniques. Although a lot was pre-defined up (by company policy/standards) front I managed to help out here and there regarding setting up an architecture.

Luckily the default template already forces you to place all Angular content in a 'ClientApp' folder. In here what we did;

- ClientApp/src

  - FeatureModule1

    - Components/Services only for this feature.
  - FeatureModule2
  - SharedModule

    - Components/Pipes/Services etc specificly shared between the features.

Next to that we have multiple .net core projects in the solution. Here we have, for example, a Base and Core project. Both of these project make use of the Angular 6' library support and is merely a library for later use which talk to the back-end of the organisation/different applications. For now the Core and Base are junctions from the original application so they can be used within the application.

In my own defense, this is an architecture used throughout the team for already more than 6 months. If I would ever start a similar project and with the same tech-stack I would rather look into other architectures.

Comment: Really appreciate for your time, I didn't get your first line "At my current project we use the exact same techniques", you mean Microservice? Latest .Net core introduced razor class library. Can't we use that to create each module and then reference them in main app which contain ClientApp?

Comment: @Sina i meant the use of .netcore and angular, sorry for the confusion! Well .net core, by default and as of Angular 4+ has updated their SPA templates; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio :)